# It is possible with itext 5 which at the end of a paragraph justified the remaining space is filled with scripts?

Tags: java, android-studio, itext, paragraphs

I am making an application on android studio and use itext pdf 5, I want every time you finish a paragraph the missing space is filled with scripts, ie :

paragraph 1:

```
text text text text end .-------------------
```

paragraph 2:

```
text text text text end .-------------------
```

etc.

Is it possible?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to obtain this? Is it because you want the last line of the paragraph to **_not_** be justified to the right margin?

Comment: I can't think of a single program that I've ever used that does this. Word, InDesign, HTML in general, nothing. The closest I've seen is when someone wants to make a TOC and fill the remaining parts of each line with a character until the page number, but those are lines, not paragraphs. That said, you should be able to measure strings and calculate things probably.

Comment: thanks for comment, I want it because this format is required by an institution and reports have always done well and yes, the last line of each paragraph must be filled with a solid line or scripts filling justified alignment , greetings .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your question is far from clear (what do you mean when you write *the missing space is filled with scripts*? what are scripts?), I'm going to assume that you want something like this:

[image]

There are plenty of examples on the official web site that involve *separators*. See the section entitled [Separator examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-building-blocks/separator-examples).

The PDF in the screen shot was created like this:

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(dest));
document.open();
DottedLineSeparator separator = new DottedLineSeparator();
Chunk c = new Chunk(separator);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Ends with dots ");
p.add(c);
document.add(p);
p = new Paragraph("This is a much longer paragraph that spans "
    + "several lines. The String used to create this paragraph "
    + "will be split automatically at the end of the line. The "
    + "final line of this paragraph will end in a dotted line. ");
p.add(c);
document.add(p);
document.close();
```

If the word *scripts* means something else, for instance if you meant to say dashes, you should use another type of separator. See for instance the answer to the question [How to create a custom dashed line separator?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-custom-dashed-line-separator) The custom `LineSeparator` created in that example can also be wrapped in a `Chunk` and that chunk can be used to extend the paragraph until the end of the line. You can move that line up and down by tweaking the `y` coordinate.

Comment: How can the same be achieved in iText 7?