# How to fill remaining space of a line in iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I'm trying to fill the remaining space of the last line of a paragraph using iText7 with C#:

```
var par = new Paragraph(text);
par.Add(c);
document.Add(par);
```

How can i add `-` char to fill the space left by the line? Something like `LineSeparator(new DashedLine()` but from the beginning on the last character of my paragraph instead of new line.

Comment: What have you tried and it did not work?

Comment: I've tried this but it's not compatible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236515/it-is-possible-with-itext-5-which-at-the-end-of-a-paragraph-justified-the-remain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the concept of tabs and tab stops for it. This concept is not iText-specific.
Roughly speaking you can define points (tab stops) and adding a tab would "jump" to the next point. In your case the tab stop is the end of the line and you only need one tab.

Here is a complete example that uses small dashes on the baseline as the filling. You can implement `ILineDrawer` yourself to customize the behavior or subclass/configure an existing implementation. The code is in Java, but to convert it to C# you basically need to do some capitalization and that's it.

```
Document doc = ....;
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Hello world").add(new Tab());
ILineDrawer filling = new DashedLine();
PageSize pageSize = doc.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize();
Rectangle effectivePageSize = doc.getPageEffectiveArea(pageSize);
float rightTabStopPoint = effectivePageSize.getWidth();
TabStop tabStop = new TabStop(rightTabStopPoint, TabAlignment.LEFT, filling);
p.addTabStops(tabStop);
doc.add(p);
```

Result looks as follows:

[image: result]

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you. Hope this can help more folks with problems like this.

Comment: is there any chance to get this on html2pdf version?

Comment: I used CustomTagWorker and I'm able to do this in htmlPDF version too